# Cabal building failling when installing idris

Tags: haskell, cabal, idris

When I run the command `sudo cabal install idris` I run into this error:

```
Build log ( /home/kyle/.cabal/logs/xss-sanitize-0.3.5.6.log ):
cabal: /home/kyle/.cabal/logs/xss-sanitize-0.3.5.6.log: does not exist
```

What can I do to fix this?

---

this is the crucial part:

```
<command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: 
    libtinfo.so (libtinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: 
                 No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, but the fact that you are using sudo to install things with cabal is itself questionable - I'd drop the sudo.  Secondly, the fact that a sudo process is still trying to write logs to a user directory is similarly questionable.

Comment: I agree - try doing it in a sandbox (you just have to add a sym-link to the bin somewhere into your path afterwards) - if this does fail kill your ~/.cabal and ~/.ghc (same for the global rep) and restart ... honestly: always use sandboxes or go for stack - also see [here](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Installing-an-Idris-Development-version-in-a-sandbox)

Comment: @Carsten I tried the sandbox, didnt work, then I nuked my .cabal and .ghc, still didnt work and I am getting the same type of error, man I hate cabal, cabal error here: http://lpaste.net/144011

Comment: @Carsten I tried that link you gave me and I am ending up with the same log error I keep getting something must be wrong with my cabal

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Since your error message is that some file does not exists - perhaps the file could not be created since your disk (quota) is full.

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 what does that mean?

Comment: can you upload the error messages when you do `cabal install free --verbose=3`?

Comment: @Carsten I tried using stack and this was the results it failed for a different reason: http://lpaste.net/145017

Comment: oh ok (you should add this to your question) - indeed I think I had this before and if I am not wrong this simply means that you have some missing dependecies to `tinfo-dev` (see the part where it says it cannot load a `.so`/`.dll` for this?) - on my linux machine I did find it in the `ncursesXY-dev` package - so try to look for it and install it - for example on ubuntu/mint/... I would go with [libncurses5-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libncurses5-dev): `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev` - ofc if you find a `tinfo-dev` you should be fine too! (ncurses don't hurt though)

Comment: @Carsten That fixed my problems! Thanks so much

Comment: I'll add it as an answer - I hope you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

if I am not wrong this simply means that you have some missing dependecies to `tinfo-dev (see the part where it says it c**annot load a .so/.dll** for this?)

on my *Linux Mint* machine I did find those libs in the `ncursesXY-dev` package - so try to look for it and install it

for *ubuntu/mint/...* I would recommend `libncurses5-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

ofc if you find a `tinfo-dev` this should be fine too!